# How to calculate the difference between two (2) dates

Tags: excel, google-sheets

im looking for calcultion of two dates (Dates - Today)  where i get Year,months and Days left from today

there is some expired dates as well which i need - year - months and - days

here is my dates are

```
02/11/2022
31/08/2020
21/01/2021
02/11/2022
02/11/2022
05/04/2023
28/02/2021
06/02/2021
06/02/2021
21/12/2020
11/02/2021
10/02/2021
01/08/2023
11/07/2023
11/09/2019
11/04/2023
13/05/2020
08/01/2023
08/01/2021
08/01/2021
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer implemented in **Excel** rather than **Google-sheets**

with data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(A1<TODAY(),"expired",DATEDIF(TODAY(),A1,"y")&" years, "&DATEDIF(TODAY(),A1,"ym")&" months, "&DATEDIF(TODAY(),A1,"md")&" days")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

If you required the *year month day* for the expired dates, use:

```
=IF(A1<TODAY()," expired " & DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"y")&" years, "&DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"ym")&" months, "&DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"md")&" days",DATEDIF(TODAY(),A1,"y")&" years, "&DATEDIF(TODAY(),A1,"ym")&" months, "&DATEDIF(TODAY(),A1,"md")&" days")
```

Comment: @Calculuswhiz  Thank you for your comment.  I have updated my answer to indicate I used *Excel* rather than *Google-sheets* to attack the formula.

Comment: Ohhh... Ok. Gotcha. I'll just add a sheets formula then!

Comment: @Calculuswhiz  Also if something like ***A1<TODAY()*** throws an error, make sure the dates in the sheet are true dates and not text values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ArrayFormula translation of Gary's Student's answer for Google Sheets, if you're using that:

```
=ArrayFormula(
    FILTER(
        IF(
            TO_DATE(A:A)<TODAY(),
            "expired",
            DATEDIF(TODAY(),A:A,"y")&" years, "&
                DATEDIF(TODAY(),A:A,"ym")&" months, "&
                DATEDIF(TODAY(),A:A,"md")&" days"
        ),
        LEN(A:A)
    )
)
```

The `TO_DATE` forces a type change to a date so the comparison will work even if the column is a number or text value.